# How to use string builder?

Tags: android

I want to display following output: 
   NAME : ***_*** 
    USN : ***_*** 
ADDRESS : ***_***

I want to display it in a single text view. When I tried using 2 text views it worked. But to use a single text view I used String builder, But when i click submit button, My application gets crashed. Why it's happening?

```
                    /*main.xml*/

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="43dp"
        android:text="@string/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="52dp"
        android:text="@string/usn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_usn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_usn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20.3dp"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_usn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_add" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/submit"/>

</RelativeLayout>


          /*layout file*/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Student Application Form</string>
    <string name="name">NAME :</string>
    <string name="edit_name">Enter your Name</string>
    <string name="usn">USN :</string>
    <string name="edit_usn">Enter the Usn</string>
    <string name="add">ADDRESS :</string>
    <string name="edit_add">Enter the Address</string>
    <string name="submit">Submit</string>
    <string name="number">1.</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_details">Details</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>

                 /*Activity_details.xml*/
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="43dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="52dp" 
        android:text="@string/usn"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20.3dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
          /*Main Activity.java*/
package com.example.assignment4;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btn;
    EditText etext1;
    EditText etext2;
    EditText etext3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        etext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_usn);
        etext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_add);
        /** Called when the user clicks the Submit button */
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", etext1.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("usn", etext2.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("address", etext3.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I passed the intent from this class to Details class. But when I click submit,it gets crashed. But Before it was working properly. After I added string builder, it started giving problem.

```
           /*Details.java*/
```

package com.example.assignment3;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Details extends ActionBarActivity {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

            //Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
            //String Builder to append strings
            StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb3=new StringBuilder();
            //Receiving the intent
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            //Extracting the string 
            String Name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
            String Usn=intent.getStringExtra("usn");
            String Address=intent.getStringExtra("address");
            //get the string from a textview
            String stext1=getString(R.id.name);
            sb1.append(stext1);
            sb1.append(Name);
            text1.setText(sb1);
            String stext2=getString(R.id.usn);
            sb2.append(stext2);
            sb2.append(Usn);
            text2.setText(sb2);
            String stext3=getString(R.id.add);
            sb3.append(stext3);
            sb3.append(Address);
            text3.setText(sb3);

        }

    }
```

I'm getting Run Time Exception and Null Pointer exception in Logcat

Comment: show your logcat error.

Comment: You forgot to initialize values of text1, text2 and text3.

Comment: Thank You...Also How to display this in a single textview: Name: rya. I want Name: in Bold and rya as a normal font

Comment: But My first part of the string is not getting diplayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to initialize textviews.

change your code like below:

```
public class Details extends ActionBarActivity {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

            text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usn);
            text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.add);

            //Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
            //String Builder to append strings
            StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb3=new StringBuilder();
            //Receiving the intent
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            //Extracting the string 
            String Name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
            String Usn=intent.getStringExtra("usn");
            String Address=intent.getStringExtra("address");
            //get the string from a textview

            String stext1= getResources().getString(R.string.name);
            text1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + stext1+ "</b>" +Name));


           String stext2= getResources().getString(R.string.usn);
            text2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + stext2+ "</b>" +Usn));


           String stext3= getResources().getString(R.string.add);
            text3.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + stext3+ "</b>" +Address));


        }

    }
```

Comment: But my first part of the string is not getting displayed

Comment: but why you are using stringbuilder..? its not require at all.

Comment: I want to concatenate the two strings. First one should be in bold and second one should be normal. If string build is not needed then how to concatenate two stings and give different styles

Comment: Thank you. but I have a doubt. What's the use of String Builder,Spannable String Builder, and Spannable. I can use Spannable also rite?

Comment: Actually this is the simple way which i used..dont know about that exactly. but yes String builder can also helpful.

Comment: I did it using html. But It's not displaying my first part.Instead its coming False for all the three rows. Output is something like this:      falseramesh                                                             false041                                                               falseIndia

Comment: because you are fetching string directly with id which is not possible. try my code.. i edited it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the text size of 2nd part of the string?

Answer (score 1):

As Simple you have just declared your `TextView` s, not initialize it

```
TextView text1;
TextView text2;
TextView text3;
```

So initialize it on `onCreate()` method

```
 text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
 text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usn);
 text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.add);
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing these:

---

`String stext1=getString(R.id.name);`

to

`String stext1=(findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();`

---

`String stext2=getString(R.id.usn);`

to

`String stext2=(findViewById(R.id.usn)).getText().toString();`

---

`String stext3=getString(R.id.add);`

to

`String stext3=(findViewById(R.id.add)).getText().toString();`